# responsive navigation hide move items to dropdown when space runs out in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation of lets say 7 items, and when resolution gets smaller items drop in a new line. I need to make that when an item doesn't fit on a navigation anymore it should put a "MORE" dropdown button on the right side of nav. and put that item that doesn't fit in a dropdown.

I need in plain javascript not in jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 function calcWidth() {
  var navwidth = 0;
  var morewidth = $('#main .more').outerWidth(true);
  $('#main > li:not(.more)').each(function() {
   navwidth += $(this).outerWidth( true );
  });
  
  
  var availablespace = $('#Mainbar').width() - morewidth;
   
  if (navwidth > availablespace) {
   var lastItem = $('#main > li:not(.more)').last();
   lastItem.attr('data-width', lastItem.outerWidth(true));
   lastItem.prependTo($('#main .more ul'));
   calcWidth();
  } else {
   
  var firstMoreElement = $('#main li.more li').first();
  if (navwidth + firstMoreElement.data('width') < availablespace) {
   firstMoreElement.insertBefore($('#main .more'));
  }
 }
   
 if ($('.more li').length > 0) {
  $('.more').css('display','block');
  } else {
   $('.more').css('display','none');
  }
 }

 $(window).on('resize load',function(){
  calcWidth();
 });
});
```

```css
#nav-main {
  *zoom: 1;
}
#nav-main:before,
#nav-main:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
}
#nav-main:after {
  clear: both;
}
#Mainbar {
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
#Mainbar > ul {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}
#Mainbar > ul > li {
  background: none;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#Mainbar > ul > li.hidden {
  display: none;
}
#Mainbar > ul > li:hover {
  background: #f00;
}
#Mainbar > ul > li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#Mainbar a {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.75;
  padding: 15px;
}
#Mainbar a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
#Mainbar ul ul {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
}
#Mainbar ul ul a {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="Mainbar">
        <ul id="main">
            <li class="selected"><a href="#" title="TITLE TEXT">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="">product</a></li>
            <li><a href="">FAQ's</a></li>
            <li class="more hidden" data-width="80">
                <a href="#">More</a>
                <ul></ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
```